# Lighthouse returned error: PROTOCOL_TIMEOUT. Waiting for DevTools protocol response has exceeded the allotted time

Tags: javascript, mobile-website, developer-tools

I have developed a website which is working OK on desktop, but it is not working fine on mobile devices. Basically, it is taking an infinite time to load some pages. This is the error I got when I checked on page speed insights Lighthouse returned error:

```
PROTOCOL_TIMEOUT.   
Waiting for DevTools protocol response has exceeded the allotted time.   
(Method: Network.emulateNetworkConditions) (PROTOCOL_TIMEOUT).
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you running LHCI in a container as part of a CI/CD?

Answer (score 3):

In case this happens in a Docker container I'd try to use `--disable-dev-shm-usage` flag for Chrome, for example see https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/6512#issuecomment-925185412. I don't know what CI/CD you use, so I cannot advise a specific `yaml` because that depends on the platform (like is it GitHub, GitLab or something else, they have their own yaml structures).

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/6512 is an umbrella ticket and you can examine various advice. According to https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse-ci/issues/504#issuecomment-740716892 your options might be limited if you use a Docker based CI/CD.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was struggling with this issue for a while, this flag fixed it for me!